# Creating AccessToken from tokenString with Uber iOS SDK failing

Tags: ios, uber-api

I'm using custom authorisation with the Uber iOS SDK, and having trouble creating the `AccessToken` in my iOS code. This is the response I get from my server with what appears to be a valid access token:

```
{
"access_token":"token here",
"expires_in":2592000,
"token_type":"Bearer",
"scope":"all_trips request",
"refresh_token":"refresh token here",
"last_authenticated":0
}
```

I then pass this to the AccessToken initialiser, like so:

```
let jsonString = //response from server as above
let accessToken = AccessToken(tokenString: jsonString)
```

My access token is created (ie. non-nil), but none of the relevant property are populated.

```
accessToken //non-nil
accessToken.expirationDate //nil
accessToken.refreshToken //nil
```

Strangely, `accessToken.tokenString` contains the original `jsonString` from above.

Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit**
Digging through the `AccessToken.swift` source file of the Uber project, I find this:

```
@objc public init(tokenString: String) {
        super.init()
        self.tokenString = tokenString
    }
```

It seems like it never actually creates the `refreshToken` etc.

Answer (score 1):

The `tokenString` is meant to be just the access token itself, as you observed. If you want to parse the JSON itself, I would suggest using the fact that the model conforms to the `Decodable` protocol, and pass in your JSON through that method.

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
let accessToken = try? decoder.decode(AccessToken.self, from: jsonData)
// If you need to convert a string to data, use String.data(using: .utf8)!
```